# Query plan reads vs statistics io reads

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, performance-tuning

I have a very strange problem. When I run a query with SET STATISTICS IO ON, it shows that I had a total of 183 reads. But when I look at the query plan dmv it shows I did 555,132 reads. I cleared the query cache before I ran my query, so I know that run was mine. Any ideas?

The reason I am checking this is I'm seeing some sort of bad parameter sniffing going on and when I look at the trace file and the query plan cache I see a query doing around 550k reads, but when I try it manually I only get 183 reads. So I'm guessing there is some setting in my SSMS that is different than the calling server where mine does not use the bad plan, but compiles a new one.

Stats I/O output:

```
Table 'Artifact'.     Scan count 1, logical reads 3,   ...
Table 'ArtifactType'. Scan count 0, logical reads 180, ...
Table 'ObjectType'.   Scan count 1, logical reads 3,   ...
```

Comment: Yes, if you are getting different plans, that would explain the difference. http://sqlperformance.com/2014/11/t-sql-queries/multiple-plans-identical-query

Comment: Yes, I knew that part (frustrating as it is) :), but what about the other part? Where SET STATISTICS IO shows 183 reads, but the DMV shows that same exact run did 555,132 reads?

Comment: I don't believe that it is conclusive that those were the same runs. You are alleging that because you cleared the plan cache first, that run must be yours, but how are you sure?

Comment: I can recreate it. I can clear it, run it once and see. Then clear it and run it twice and see. And even cleared it and ran it 13 times and it shows 13 executions.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the STATISTICS IO output, the relevant columns from the DMV, and the actual execution plan (not the estimated garbage that's in the plan cache)?

Comment: Please put statistics IO output etc. in the question. Absolutely unreadable in the comments. And post the XML file somewhere (that doesn't require logging in) and link to it. Don't even think about posting all of the XML into the question, never mind a comment.

Comment: Can you post your code?  I ready recently where inline functions will not show up in SHOW STATISTICS IO but will show up in the query plan as the function runs on each 'iteration' of the data returned.